# How do I reset “Client ID” of Instagram?

Tags: client, instagram

We find that some bad guys are stealing our Instagram Client ID. That's pretty bad and we'd like to reset the client ID. But we only find option to reset Client Secret on Instagram Developer Portal. How do we reset Client ID?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary for you to reset your Client ID. As long as they don't have your Client Secret they won't be able to generate and send the correct access token and they won't be able to access anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really prevent people from stealing `client_id`, if you have to do oauth login, then your `client_id` will be in the authorization URL, so anyone can see it even if you reset it.

People can use your `client_id` to make API calls and use up your API limits. Usually you can do only simple GET API calls  using `client_id`, so they can't do bad stuff like commenting/follow/unfollow with just `client_id`. So you should not rely on `client_id` to make API calls in your app, you should ask user to login and use their `access_token` to make API calls.